# Nodejs web server calling requestListener twice when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following is the example web server from the documentation, with an added counter.  It prints the counter to the console whenever a client/browser requests the page.

However, it's being called twice when requested by the browser.  Why?

This is what I would expect would happen:

```
browser : Hello World 1
console : Counter 1
[reload page]
browser : Hello World 2
console : Counter 2
```

but this happens:

```
browser : Hello World 1
console : Counter 1
          Counter 2
[reload page]
browser : Hello World 3
console : Counter 3
          Counter 4
```

I run the code using the command line

```
$ node example.js
```

Here is the code:

```
  var 
    http = require('http'),
    counter = 0,
    sys = require('util');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    counter++;
    res.end('Hello World ' + counter + '\n');
    sys.puts('Counter ' + counter);
  }).listen(8000, "");
```

Comment: The first time I ran this I got similar behavior, but on subsequent runs it works as expected.

Comment: Perhaps its how I am running it. I am just using the command line 'node example.js'. How do you run it?

Comment: Ran it from the command line like you

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In programming, when stuck, it's always handy to trace the code to better understand what's happening. The easiest way to do this is to put more debug/print statements in till you can see what's going on.

Change the sys.puts line to:

```
sys.puts('Counter ' + counter + " from " + req.url);
```

I think you'll find that the 2nd request is the browser requesting the favicon for the site.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thank you very much bxjx.

Comment: @bxjx: You are right but since i am novice to nodejs. How should i avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

We can ignore the page refresh count due to favicon with the following code snippet:

```
if (request.url === '/favicon.ico') {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
   response.end();
   console.log('favicon requested');
   return;
}
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/763822