# Why console is log twice but not res on http.createServer function?

Tags: node.js

I have my code below

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end("My URL:" + req.url);
  console.log("My URL:" + req.url);
}).listen(8080);
```

When I run it and hit my localhost:8080, the console print as below

```
My URL:/
My URL:/favicon.ico
```

This is aligned with what https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939334/3286489 shared.

However, on my webpage, it has only

```
My URL:/
```

Why wasn't `My URL:/favicon.ico` shown as well?

**Update**
Just to answer has I disabled cached.. Yes. It is as shown below

[image]

Comment: Have you disabled your browser's cache before you loaded the site on your webpage? The favicon may have been already in cache.

Comment: Yes, I have disabled cache, as per my update on my question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my node server though. I just tried it, it always prompts the favicon.ico into the console, no matter what. Literally running some ancient version `v10.15.2`.

Comment: @Elye I think you are misunderstanding how the request/response works here. In your console, you can correctly see two console.logs but on the webpage you can see only one `My URL: /` line. **And that is correct behavior**. The second `My URL: /favicon.ico` line will be responded to the `/favicon.ico` request, which is a separate request and the reponse can bee seen after clicking on the `favicon.ico` request in the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks @maio290 and @SebastianKaczmarek. I don't expect favicon line to be shown on the browser. I'm just curious how the code would be able to recognize that it's favicon and skip processing it from showing in the browser (since I didn't put and if-else there to check). FYI, I'm a mobile dev, new to node.js, just curious on how it works, and why those code `res.end("My URL:" + req.url);` and `console.log("My URL:" + req.url);` is next to each other, but only one is executed when `favicon` is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser will only show the response of the requested url (`/`), not the response of `/favicon.ico`.

Do you really expect that your favicon is displayed on the web page? It would be non-sense.

The `/favicon.ico` request is sent by the browser to see if the tab icon has to be customized, but since you don't send a valid `.ico` data file, I guess this is just ignored by the browser.

Comment: Thanks @yolenoyer. I don't expect favicon line to be shown on the browser. I'm just curious how the code would be able to recognize that it's favicon and skip processing it from showing in the browser (since I didn't put and if-else there to check). FYI, I'm a mobile dev, new to node.js, just curious on how it works, and why those code `res.end("My URL:" + req.url);` and `console.log("My URL:" + req.url);` is next to each other, but only one is executed when `favicon` is loaded.

Comment: "but only one is executed when favicon is loaded": no, everything is executed. As Sebastian Kaczmarek wrote, the first request `/` is rendered into you browser view, since the `/favicon.ico` request can be viewed in your Dev Tools tab: click on "favicon.ico", then click on the "Response" tab on the right, then you will see `My URL:/favicon.ico`

Comment: In a normal website, tens of requests are sent to the server (you can check it with Dev Tools, e.g. for this SO page). But only the requested url (the one your entered in the location bar) will be really rendered in the web view.

Comment: Very nicely explained. I tried with `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico`, and it does render it, but it still calls it's own `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico`. The second call to `Thanks for the explanations.` is perhaps to display the icon, which will not be visible to the browser then I suppose. Thanks!